# asp .net query string encoding and decoding

Tags: asp.net, query-string, url-encoding, urldecode

I type the following url into my web browser and press enter.

```
http://localhost/website.aspx?paymentID=6++7d6CZRKY%3D&language=English
```

Now in my code when I do HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["paymentID"],

I get 6  7d6CZRKY=

but when I do HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString() I see the following:

paymentID=6++7d6CZRKY%3D&language=English

The thing I want to extract the actual payment id that the user typed in the web browser URL. I am not worried as to whether the url is encoded or not. Because I know there is a weird thing going on here %3D and + sign at the same time ! But I do need the actual + sign. Somehow it gets decoded to space when I do HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["paymentID"].

I just want to extract the actual payment ID that the user typed. What's the best way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to encode the URL first, using URLEncode(). **+** in URL equals a space so needs to be encoded to %2b.

```
string paymentId = Server.UrlEncode("6++7d6CZRKY=");
// paymentId = 6%2b%2b7d6CZRKY%3d
```

And now

```
string result = Request.QueryString["paymentId"].ToString();
//result = 6++7d6CZRKY=
```

However

```
string paymentId = Server.UrlEncode("6  7d6CZRKY=");
//paymentId looks like you want it, but the + is a space -- 6++7d6CZRKY%3d

string result = Request.QueryString["paymentId"].ToString();
//result = 6 7d6CZRKY=
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if the URL that is in HttpContext.Current.Request is encoded or not! So as of now I just wrote a function to extract the payment id value out of it (Francis's approach is using regular expression).

Comment: Probably want to find that out. Other method is not recommended.

Comment: Actually the url which we receive is not in correct format. It has a + symbol in it and our client does mean that's its a plus symbol. They should have put %2B instead of +. And now we need to come up with some kind of hacky solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is some info on this here: [Plus sign in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string).

But I suppose you could also use a regular expression to get your parameter out of the query string. Something like this:

```
string queryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString();
string paramPaymentID = Regex.Match(queryString, "paymentID=([^&]+)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I sent an Arabic text in my query string

[image: Arabic text in my query string]

and when I resieved this string it was Encoded 
[image]

after `Server.UrlDecode`

```
 departmentName = Server.UrlDecode(departmentName);
```

it back again to arabic
[image]

I hope this help you