# get Request.QueryString as it show

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
VerifyEmail.aspx?key=KMSO+tLs5zY=&val=ALKXZzxNxajUWVMaddKfPG/FcFD111CD
```

`Request.QueryString["key"].ToString()` gives me `"KMSO tLs5zY="`

i want key value `"KMSO+tLs5zY="`

Comment: So it "eats" the + symbol?

Comment: Check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string

Answer (score 4):

If you can modify the url parameter, you can encode the values using the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method, for example:

```
string url = "VerifyEmail.aspx?key=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("KMSO+tLs5zY=");
```

Another method is to use Base64 encoding

```
string url = "VerifyEmail.aspx?key=" + EncodeTo64("KMSO+tLs5zY=");
```

and decoding the value reading the querystring

```
String value = DecodeFrom64(Request["key"]);
```

the code for the EncodeTo64 and DecodeFrom64 is available in this article http://arcanecode.com/2007/03/21/encoding-strings-to-base64-in-c/

Comment: It's strange, but if you have problem with special chars you can use Base64 encoding for parameters. In this article there is an example of Base64 encoding and decoding: http://arcanecode.com/2007/03/21/encoding-strings-to-base64-in-c/ remember to decode the value before use it.

Answer (score -2):

Do not use `%2B` instead of  `+` when producing url.

And if you get %2B's itself when requesting, do not try to replace it using

```
Request.QueryString["key"].ToString().Replace("%2B","+")
```

Use HttpUtility class' UrlEncode() method:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("KMSO+tLs5zY=")
```

(:

Comment: Replacement is the wrong answer. URL encoding is the right answer.