# MVC ASP.NET querystring incorrect

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with my querystring, i call an action in my controller with javascript like this

```
if ((event >= 65) && (event <= 90) || (event >= 48) && (event <= 57)) {
    var focussed = document.activeElement.id;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        alert(in2.value);
        location.href = "/CarSaldi/ListaArt?in1=" + in1.value + "&in2=" + in2.value + "&focus=" + focussed;
    }, 1000);
}
```

in2 is a input text and might have a "+" inside it (for example "milk+chocolate"), when i call the action in my controller

```
public ActionResult ListaArt(string in1, string in2, string cod, string focus)
{
    [...]
}
```

the string in2 shows my "milk chocolate", i expected milk+chocolate...i need to have also the "+" inside.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6855723/148998

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plus sign in query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use java script function `encodeURIComponent` to encode url.

```
location.href = "/CarSaldi/ListaArt?in1=" + encodeURIComponent(in1.value) 
 + "&in2=" + encodeURIComponent(in2.value) + "&focus=" + encodeURIComponent(focussed);
```

You need to change you code as follows

```
if ((event >= 65) && (event <= 90) || (event >= 48) && (event <= 57)) {
var focussed = document.activeElement.id;
window.setTimeout(function () {
    alert(in2.value);
    location.href = "/CarSaldi/ListaArt?in1=" + encodeURIComponent(in1.value) 
 + "&in2=" + encodeURIComponent(in2.value) + "&focus=" + encodeURIComponent(focussed);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `encodeURIComponent(yourParameter)`.

In this case special characters are not lost

Answer (score 1):

Plus sign should be URL encoded in your case:

```
 +   =  %2B
```

So instead of using '**+**' in the URL use '**%2B**'

See the full table of URL encoded characters: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Comment: so i can do replace in javascript with %2b

Comment: @theLaw Yes, for example

Comment: @theLaw better use built-in encodeURIComponent(string) function

Answer (score 1):

Encode your string using the **javascript function** `encodeURIComponent`:

you can use:

```
 encodeURIComponent(in1.value)
```

Answer (score -1):

Never, never, never construct your query string in asp.net mvc using javascript and string conatenation. Always let this to `Url.Action`. The main reason is that what is left on querystring and what is inside the pathinfo depends on how your routes are defined. If you want to give yourself the chance to change your routes easily in the future, use always `Url.Action`:

```
var uri = "@Url.Action("ListaArt", CarSaldi", new {in1="xxx", in2="yyy", focus="zzz"})".replace("&amp;","&");
// Replace the "placeholders" values to the real ones
uri = uri.replace("xxx", in1.value);
uri = uri.replace("yyy", in2.value);
uri = uri.replace("yyy", focussed);
location.href = uri;
```

And regarding the plus sign you need to use encodeURIComponent method in Javascript:

```
uri = uri.replace("yyy", encodeURIComponent(in2.value));
```

Hope this helps!

PS: The `replace("&amp;","&")` is needed because `Url.Action` generates URLs using & instead of & for separating the tokens of the querystring. This is good for HTML (you can put this in the href of a A tag) but not for the location.href property.