# What is the correct way to encode querystring in javascript and decode properly on asp.net-mvc serverside?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I had an asp.net-mvc site and I have an issue where I had an "&" in my  query string that I am building with javascript and then using ajax to my server. Something like this:

```
 www.mysite.com/MyController/Load?Tag=M&Ms
```

when I passed this to my server using ajax, it was showing up as

```
Tag="M"
```

so, in my javascript code, I changed my code from this:

```
  "Load?Tag=" + tag;
```

to:

```
  "Load?Tag=" + encodeURIComponent(tag);
```

and this fixed my issue. My server code looks like this

```
 public ActionResult Load(ProjectParams projectParams)
 {
      //go do stuff
 }
```

where ProjectParams looks like this:

```
public class ProjectParams
{
    public string Tag {get;set;}
}
```

So everything was great until I realized that making this change on the javascript side, had a knockon effect. I just ran into an issue where if I have spaces in my tag name, it shows up on the server as:

```
  My%20Tag%20Name
```

instead of:

```
  My Tag Name
```

what is the correct way to encode on the javascript side for a url querystring and ensure that it shows up properly on the serverside controller action

Comment: did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211229/in-a-url-should-spaces-be-encoded-using-20-or

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012472/mvc-asp-net-querystring-incorrect

Comment: @McArthey - this question says "Use encodeURIComponent" on the javascript side which i specified in my question that i am already doing

Comment: @leora Maybe you should attribute Tag property with [AllowHtml]

Comment: @kanchirk - this seems like a very odd way to solve this issue.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @leora: I would expect that MVC would automatically decode the Query String parameter in that scenario; it's peculiar that it isn't. I assume you've confirmed that it isn't getting double-encoded somehow? I.e., that your Query String reads, literally, `Tag=My%20Tag%20Name` and not `Tag=My%2520Tag%2520Name`? Worst case you could work around this using .NET's `UrlDecode()` method (e.g., from `WebUtility` or `HttpUtility`), but that's obviously not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

you can decode it easily with

```
Server.UrlDecode()
```

and you could do that on the setter