# Query cannot find "+" character using Rally API in C#

Tags: c#, rally

Using Rally's rest API in C#, I have been trying to create a query that will find a test case that contains the character "+".  When I create a test case using the API, the + sign makes it into the project without issue and is displayed correctly.  When I then perform a query to find the test case with the "+" in the name, nothing is returned.  I noticed when debugging that the query operator is converting from "+" to "%2B" and does not return a result that matches the test case name.  How can I get my query to find test case names that contain the "+" sign?  Additionally, I cannot seem to get test cases that contain the following characters to be found either:  &, #, %, “”.  My code for the query request:

```
string testName = "Example+";

  Request requestTC = new Request("TestCase");
        requestTC.Project = rallyProjectRef;
        requestTC.ProjectScopeDown = false;
        requestTC.ProjectScopeUp = false;
        requestTC.Fetch = new List<string> { "Name", "ObjectID", "TestFolder" };
        requestTC.Query = new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, testName);
        bool noMatchesFound = true;
            QueryResult findTCMatchQueryResult = m.myRestApi.Query(requestTC);
```

Comment: Look up URL Encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters

Answer (score 0):

True, this does not work:

```
testcaseRequest.Query = new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, "Example+");
```

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string), + sign in the query string is URL-decoded to a space. %2B in the query string is URL-decoded to a + sign.

However this does not work either:

```
 testcaseRequest.Query = new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, "Example%2B");
```

I submitted a defect DE21028. Fixed defects appear on [what's new](https://help.rallydev.com/whats-new) page.