# Plus sign in query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, url-encoding

I have a webapp created using C# and asp.net. I placed a parameter value in the querystring with a plus(+) sign. But the plus sign disappear.

How can I include the plus sign(+) in the query string without disappearing?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string) I found the same question and according to it, I have used `Server.UrlEncode(myqerystring)` and the time of decoding `Server.UrlDecode(myqerystring)` but some how it always resolves to the `SPACE` here is watch window 
[image]

```
 1) Querystring after the Server.UrlEncode()
 2) Querystring after the Server.UrlDecode()
```

notice the space between `S` and `R` it should be `+`. I am new to all web development and I read other answers which says use `UrlEncode and decode` but it giving the same issue as before am I doing something wrong and yes the query string is automatically generated. I have no control over it.
There is other hack replace the " " or "%2b" with "+" I will go to that if I dont find any good way. So is there any good way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you link to just mentions using Server.UrlEncode, not Server.UrlDecode. When you read from Request.Querystring it automatically decodes the string for you. Doing it manually a second time is corrupting it and is why you're getting a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx

Although this might help

```
string destinationURL = "http://www.contoso.com/default.aspx?user=test";
NextPage.NavigateUrl = "~/Finish?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(destinationURL);
```

Regarding plus sign you can not do this as '+' sign has semantic meaning in query string 
Take a look at [Plus sign in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string)

**EDIT**
Have you used '+' sign while using google search. This provide different results.

Comment: Yes I have been using these methods and i have mentioned same question link but the issue is still if you read my description ?

Comment: Also if you take look at image it encoded `%2b` is ther but somehow `UrlDecode` not decoding it as `+` it is decoding it as `space`

Comment: Yes I know that so i am trying to decode the querystring at back end code so it should generate `+` sign but it is not generating it and I am asking why is that ?

Comment: + sign has a semantic meaning in the query string. It is used to represent a space. Another character that has semantic importance in the query string is & which is used to separate the various var=value pairs in the query string. Take a look at accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string

Comment: Copied from that answer solution is "So, if you want the + sign to be preserved when a JavaScript is fetching a URL with + signs in its query parameters and a server side script would process the query parameters after URL-decoding it, `you should URL-encode the query parameters in the URL` before using issuing the HTTP get request so that `all + signs are converted to %2B's` when the request reaches the server side script. Now when the server side script `URL-decodes the query string, all %2B's gets converted back to + signs` which is what you want." and I have tried that but its not working