# QueryString not displaying all text in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have **url** below,

```
http://localhost:34349/page.aspx?RUD=Pby0lPWu+dc=
```

If i use below code in **page.cs** load method

```
 string result = Request.QueryString["RUD"].ToString();
```

**result** displays below value

```
Pby0lPWu dc=
```

"**+**" character is missing while **Request.QueryString**. Where i **miss** exactly while using querystring in asp.net ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plus sign in query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string)

Comment: Basically because a + is the URL Encoded character for a space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 string result = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["RUD"].ToString());
```