# Special chars in query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, query-string

I am passing a query string parameter containing file name.

`default.aspx?file=Fame+ adlabs.xml` (`Fame+ adlabs.xml` is the actual file name on server). The file name has "+" & also blank spaces.

When I check for file name from query string as follows:

```
   var fileName = Request.QueryString["file"];
```

The variable filename does not have a "+" in it. It reads as `"Fame adlabs.xml"` & hence I get a file not found exception. I cannot rename the xml files. Can someone please guide me into right direction.

***Thanks***

Comment: You can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string)

Comment: @iuliu.net thanks a lot, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do it at the server in C#:

```
String FileName = "default.aspx?";

String FullURL = FileName + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Fame + adlabs.xml");

String Decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(FullURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should URL encode into your javascript before sending it :

```
var name = "Fame+ adlabs.xml";
var url = "default.aspx?file=" + encodeURIComponent(name);
```

Pay attention that following char won't work : `~!*()'`

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I cannot change the code on sender page, I must handle this from redirected page.

Comment: Woo. Rude Philippe, rude.