# How to use plus in query params instead of %20 with vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm creating a component that will append query param to current url based on user input. This is the method to change the url.

```
submitSearch () {
  this.$router.push({query: {search: this.search ? this.search : undefined}})
},
```

Submitting "john doe" will change the url into http://mysite.test?search=john%20doe

How to make it use + instead? expected url: http://mysite.test?search=john+doe

Comment: maybe helpful [Plus sign in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string)

Comment: @bpGusar I'm not talking about + into %2B, but to make vue-router encode space to (+) instead of %20

Comment: Why is it necessary, that `+` is used instead of `%20`?

Comment: why did you need exactly plus in query string?

Comment: just for readability as (+) is more user friendly.

Comment: friendly for who? for users? normal user write query in browser address field or in input?

Comment: @bpGusar I mean readability, for reading, not for typing.

Comment: it doesn't matter is plus sign or is %20, just parse this query string to normal view using functions, like ```encodeURIComponent()```, as in link in comment i poster above

Comment: did you use backend? to process the request

Comment: @bpGusar sorry I don't understand, what do you mean by "process the request"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**
Vue 3 uses '+' by default, so you don't need to do this anymore. But if for some reason you need to use Vue 2, you can use the code below.

=========

Found out that we can [override vue-router default querystring parser](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#parsequery-stringifyquery) .

I'm using [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) for the parser as shown in [this answer from Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1259#issuecomment-306000548)

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode            : 'history',
  linkActiveClass : 'active',
  stringifyQuery  : query => {
    let result = qs.stringify(query, { format: 'RFC1738' })
    return result ? ('?' + result) : ''
  },
  routes,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URI encoding for value parts of query strings, like this:

http://example.com/?param1=(uri-encoded-value)&param2=(uri-encoded-value)&...

You can encode these values using the native function **encodeURIComponent**.

Example:

```
const toUrl = (baseUrl = "/", queryObject = {}) => {
  return [
    baseUrl, 
    Object.keys(queryObject).map(k => `${k}=${encodeURIComponent(queryObject[k])}`).join('&')
  ].filter(x => x).join('?')
}
```

Comment: Same approach can we used for decoding, with decodeURIComponent function

Comment: It will depend on your usage. I can't tell you just by the code fragment you provided.

Answer (score -1):

It enters an endless loop redirecting to fullPath over and over. Set a condition that checks for `%20` in URL String.

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
if(to.fullPath.includes('%20')) {
  let fullPath = to.fullPath.replace('%20', '+')
  next(fullPath)
} else {
  next()
}
},
```

Comment: I still got %20 in the url.