# How does Javascript treat hyphens?

Tags: javascript, xss

I am looking at [XSS Game](https://xss.pwnfunction.com/) and this one challenge called [Jeff](https://xss.pwnfunction.com/warmups/jefff/).

The challenge takes a query parameter called `jeff` as input, and stores it in a variable named `jeff`. The goal of the challenge is to load an alert box on the page. The solution uses hyphens to run Javascript within an `eval()` function.

So, we have this eval:

```
eval(`ma = "Ma name ${jeff}"`)
```

And the solution input to get an alert box is (Spoiler alert! No pun intended.):

```
"-alert(1337)-"
```

Now, I am in desperate need of understanding how Javascript treats those hyphens! Help!?

Comment: The result of the eval is `ma = "Ma name "-alert(1337)-""`, so it's the initial quote that's important, not the hyphens (which are just treated as normal subtractions). `";alert(1337);//` would be another valid solution.

Comment: Yeah, reading the linked post 10 times does not give me any good clues of how Javascript treats the hyphen to make the XSS work..

Comment: You're right - this doesn't result in a unary operator (e.g. `ma = -x`), it results in 2 standard operators, e.g. `ma = A - B - C`.

Comment: Thanks, @cmbuckley. The initial quotes makes sense, I solved it with the semicolon myself. I still don't understand the hyphens role for making the alert work. Why would it work to subtract, but not to use plus instead?

Comment: @Quentin I don't think this has anything to do with unary -. The - is needed (on both sides) to make the syntax valid when connect the end of the first string literal with an expression that follows it.

Comment: It doesn't really matter *which* operator you use. It's an operator and you can separate expressions with operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code that the site uses is:

```
let jeff = (new URL(location).searchParams.get('jeff') || "JEFFF")
eval(`ma = "Ma name ${jeff}"`)
```

Note that `searchParams` gives you a `URLSearchParams` object, and its `.get` method gives you a *string* corresponding to the parameter. So, the objective is to come up with some characters that, when inserted into

```
ma = "Ma name <CHARACTERS>"
```

and run, results in arbitrary code execution.

First step is to surround the characters in `"`s, so as to end the string literal after the `name` and resume a string literal after the CHARACTERS:

```
ma = "Ma name " <SOMETHING ELSE> ""
```

So now you need to figure out what sort of characters can go into `<SOMETHING ELSE>` which will result in valid Javascript code.

If you just put in `alert()`, that won't be valid:

```
ma = "Ma name " alert() ""
```

That's a syntax error. You need something to indicate what the `alert` has to do with the string literal token that comes just before it. A `-` can do the trick, but so could any other operator, like `+`, `%`, and so on. You also need to connect the end of the `alert` with the resumed string literal, thus the need for another operator at the end:

```
ma = "Ma name "-alert('foo')-""
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
ma = "Ma name "-alert('foo')-""
```

So, the characters that need to be inserted are:

```
"-alert('foo')-"
```

Note that because the string is delivered inside of a search parameter, a `+` won't be interpreted as the literal character `+` - rather, it'll be [interpreted as a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string). So [`jeff="+alert(1337)+"`](https://sandbox.pwnfunction.com/warmups/jefff.html?jeff=%22%2balert(1337)%2b%22) won't work, but [`jeff="%2balert(1337)%2b"`](https://sandbox.pwnfunction.com/warmups/jefff.html?jeff=%22%2balert(1337)%2b%22) will.

Semicolons work as well, because they result in:

```
ma = "Ma name " <SOMETHING ELSE> ""
ma = "Ma name "; alert()        ;""
```

which is valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense!! :100: