# Net core api, get parameter with special character

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I am trying to receive a parameter by URL, but if this parameter has a '+' I do not receive it, for example:

```
www.domain.com/api/controller/Demo?guid=123+456

[HttpPost("Demo")]
public IActionResult PostData([FromQuery]string guid, Model model)
{
```

Inside the function, the guid value is **123 456**

Comment: Search "URL encoding".

Comment: the problem is not in the construction of the URL, it is that the api removes the + from the parameter

Comment: Have you tried checking `Request.Query`?

Comment: @juunas equal, result without +

Comment: Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6855723/6751634

Answer (score 2):

> if this parameter has a '+' I do not receive it, for example: `www.domain.com/api/controller/Demo?guid=123+456`. Inside the function, the guid value is **123 456**

To achieve your requirement, you can try following approaches:

**Approach 1**: manually replace the `+` sign to `%2B` while client make request to your API action.

**Approach 2**: encode query string `guid=123+456` by using [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1), like below.

*In Startup.cs*

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    using (StreamReader iisUrlRewriteStreamReader =
            File.OpenText("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
    {
        var options = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddIISUrlRewrite(iisUrlRewriteStreamReader);

        app.UseRewriter(options);
    }

    //...
}
```

*In IISUrlRewrite.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
      <rule name="TESTURL">
            <match url="api/your_controller_name/Demo" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="guid=([0-9]+\+[0-9]+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="api/your_controller_name/Demo?guid={UrlEncode:{C:1}}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule> 
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

*Test Result*

[image]