# How to retain special characters in url parameters for flask?

Tags: flask

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/segment?text=PA++

text = request.args.get('text')
```

What I get is 'PA', not 'PA++'.

How to not lose the plus signs in URL? I want to use urllib.urlencode(text) to encode it somehow, but how to get a handle of the 'text' string? because it comes from the request.args.get() function. By the time it returns the values, the special characters are already chopped off.

EDITED:

```
@api.route('/segment', methods=['GET'])
def segment():
    text = request.args.get('text')
    seg = str(segmenter.segment(text))
    return seg
```

I don't have any html page or template. Then in the browser, I can make reqeust:

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000/segment?text=PA++
```

But the problem is:

```
text = request.args.get('text')
```

the returned 'text' is already reduced to 'PA', no plus sign.

Comment: `+` is reserved for a space.  You need to hit: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/segment?text=PA%2B%2B` which lands the correct string in `text`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6855723/2052575) for further info.

Comment: @v25 Yes， I want to use urlEncoder, but how to use it in request.args.get('text'). It seems I don't have a chance to use it. The get() function already removed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to achieve needs to be done on the frontend before form submission.

As mentioned you need to hit `http://127.0.0.1:3000/segment?text=PA%2B%2B` in the browser.  So the encoding takes place on the frontend.  A standard form should do this automatically, so if you consider this sample app:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app=Flask(__name__)

template="""
<form action='/segment' method='GET'>
<input name='text' type='text' /> 
<input type='submit' />
</form>
"""

@app.route('/segment')
def index():    
    text = request.args.get('text')

    if text:
        print ('Server got: ', text)
        return f"result was: {text}"
    else:
        return template
```

If you enter `PA++` in the input field, and click the submit button:

- the resulting URL in the browser is: `http://localhost:5000/segment?text=PA%2B%2B`
- the server console prints: `Server got:  PA++`
- the browser renders: `result was: PA++`

---

Similarly if you wanted to do this without a form (which appears to handle the encoding automatically) you [could do so in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332888/2052575), for example at your dev tools JS console:

```
>> encoded = '/segment?text=' + encodeURIComponent('PA++')
"/segment?text=PA%2B%2B"
```

---

The Python requests library also does this encoding automatically:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r=requests.get('http://localhost:5000/segment', params = {'text':'PA++'})
>>> r.url
'http://localhost:5000/segment?text=PA%2B%2B'
>>> r.text
'result was: PA++'
```

- Server also outputs: `Server got:  PA++`

And finally for demonstration purposes, with a space in that string:

```
>>> r=requests.get('http://localhost:5000/segment', params = {'text':'P A'})
>>> r.url
'http://localhost:5000/segment?text=P+A'
>>> r.text
'result was: P A'
```

- Server output: `Server got:  P A`

Comment: "If you enter PA++ in the input field", please see my edits. I don't use any html form. I simply make a request in the browser's address box. In this situation, how to encode it in my segment function above?

Comment: @marlon You can't as far as I understand.  Because any `+` in the URL string becomes a space by the time it reaches the server.  Thus the solution is to encode the `+` in advance, so it's sent as `%2B`.  As this answer shows, there are a number of ways to do this with client side scripts.