# Unable to fetch '+' sign in the value of a parameter from a link in PHP

Tags: php

I need to fetch the value of parameters but if a parameter contains a '+' sign like (g + 6) then it's only giving me (g 6), it's ignoring the '+' sign.

```
<?PHP
$volume = $_GET['vol'];
$title = $_GET['title'];
echo $title;
?>
```

am doing this but if title = "(g+6)" it's giving (g 6) ignoring the '+' sign

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Specifically - `$sql = "select * from `$volume` where title = '$title' and author = '$author'";` takes whatever is passed in through the URL for `title` and `author` and sends directly to the database. Using params as mentioned in my other comment will protect your database against injections

Comment: Please don't change your question because we pick on your insecure SQL queries. We are trying to help you with your question but also look at other potential issues.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string