# Lambda Proxy integration queryStringParameters special characters

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm in the midst of testing a new AWS SAM application, and I found a bug that i'm having trouble solving.

I have a route with a simple GET request

```
/myRoute
```

and this route support query params such as "mail"

so the full url looks something like this

```
/myroute?mail=mymail@example.com
```

aws is creating the proper event for me my problem lies when I have special characters inside my string params for example mymail+bonzo@example.com than what I'll actually get after aws-sam interpret the call is "mymail bonzo@example.com" with a space instead of the special character +.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an issue with SAM, Lambda, or API Gateway. The `+` symbol indicates a space ([see this answer on that subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6855723/2860032)). You should URL encode your query string parameters, and decode them in your Lambda. The `+` symbol is `%2B`.

Comment: I thought when Lambda Proxy integration create event their might be some option that can deal with this.
This answer is good enough though