# Query string replacing + sign with space " "

Tags: c#

I just sent my application URL to user in email with query sting contains different variable with values just see below. As it can be seen I just encrypt the values of variables. He needs to click URL and come to my application this is the scenario.

http://225.XXX.206.XX/VendorInvoiceApprovalService?InvoiceRecIdString=M2r4iw/MewTIIw01YS4Cpg==&UserId=r13jfB8PDQ2hLtq8vTh32g==&EmailId=GZfCFBZLRF/wh+sqkeEYoGqrdGU22oh9sS2a1fDy4FqmArda9/CvG5lsL8/LitJY&Company=3LIHJYmHQc92ULjj1JXIhw==

But when I got these query string in my C# code like I have issue in Email value.

```
EmailId=GZfCFBZLRF/wh+sqkeEYoGqrdGU22oh9sS2a1fDy4FqmArda9/CvG5lsL8/LitJY
```

this is actual value

but when I use below line of code + sign is being replaced with space.

```cs
string email = Request.QueryString["EmailId"];
```

```
GZfCFBZLRF/wh sqkeEYoGqrdGU22oh9sS2a1fDy4FqmArda9/CvG5lsL8/LitJY
```

in above line + sign is being replaced with space.

How could I get my query string value without any change.
Already used

```cs
Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["EmailId"])
```

It corrects the space issue and provide the + but replacing  / with % so another issue is being created.

So please provide the solution.

Comment: To keep the plus sign it must be inside a pair of double quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plus sign in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string)

Answer (score 0):

To use special characters you should use UrlEncode and UrlDecode

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
```

Comment: I got + character in place but it replaced / with %2f and again I am having issue in Encrypting. but thank u so much.

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: when I use this method HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value); it replaces / with %2f. so again when  I use decrypt I am  having issue.

Comment: can you please explain what u r doing. you want to send the email encrypted as a querystring?