# Get special character from query params in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In a listing API frontend pass a tag called `coutryCode` its value will be like `+91`, `+66` etc. 
When its recieved on backend (NodeJS, ExpressJS) it looks like  `91`. The `+` symbol turned into a space. 
How can I get it properly in NodeJs application?

```
const countryCode =  req.query.countryCode;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string

Comment: `const countryCode =  req.query.countryCode.replace(/^\s(.+)/, '+$1');`?

Comment: Fix the frontend so it properly URL encodes the `+`. Don't try hacks like assuming all spaces are really plusses.

Comment: What if the "frontend" is a user who types `http://server/api?countryCode=+91` into their address bar?

Comment: If your frontend is build in JavaScript that's running in a browser, use `encodeURIComponent`; that will result in, e.g., `%2B91` for `+91`.