# How to handle '+' sign in fetch api?

Tags: javascript, react-native, get, fetch-api

Here is my code:

```
function GETdynamoDBapi(phoneNumber) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fetch(
            'https://api?phoneNumber=' +
                phoneNumber
        )
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((res) => {
                resolve(data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
}
```

I have tried following two case of with and without `+`. I have both '4100000000' and  '+4100000000' data on my database table. Phone Number is defined as string in database.

```
let response = await GETdynamoDBapi('+4100000000'); //error return data
```

```
let response = await GETdynamoDBapi('4100000000'); //return date success
```

How can I handle the '+' sign? Thanks!

(edited)
I also tried to test the API https://api?phoneNumber=+4100000000 on Insomnia and it works well. But when I try following in my code, it cannot return any data.

```
        fetch(
            'https://api?phoneNumber=+4100000000'
        )
```

Comment: handle what plus sign? is there a plus sign in `phoneNumber` variable? if so ... remove it

Comment: Apply proper URL encoding to the value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the value:

```js
fetch(`https://api?phoneNumber=${encodeURIComponent(phoneNumber)}`)
```

This way, it will turn into e.g. `phoneNumber=%2B1234567890` so that when decoding on the server it will turn back into `+1234567890`. The `+` may otherwise be [interpreted as a space character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6855723/1871033) on the server.

You should *always* encode query arguments, otherwise you will have a bug at the very least and a security vulnerability at the worst.

Another, more expressive way would be to use `URLSearchParams`:

```js
fetch(`https://api?${new URLSearchParams({ phoneNumber })}`)
```

Or a `URL` object:

```js
const url = new URL('https://api')
url.searchParams.set('phoneNumber', phoneNumber)
fetch(url)
```

Or, you could use a tagged template function like [`uri-tag`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uri-tag):

```js
import uri from 'uri-tag'

fetch(uri`https://api?phoneNumber=${phoneNumber}`)
```

---

On another note: You are using the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). There is no need for any `new Promise` because `fetch` already returns a promise, otherwise you couldn't do `.then`!

```js
function GETdynamoDBapi (phoneNumber) {
  return fetch(`https://api?${new URLSearchParams({ phoneNumber })}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
}
```

Or you could make the function `async` and use `await`, then it would be even easier to maintain in case more logic is added and would be consistent with your other functions for which you apparently already use `async`/`await`:

```js
async function GETdynamoDBapi (phoneNumber) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api?${new URLSearchParams({ phoneNumber })}`)
  return await response.json()
}
```

<sub>Preemptive comment: [Read here as for why I do use `return await`](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/1442).</sub>