# Why does removingPercentEncoding() not replace '+' like it does with %20?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two strings encoded differently for spacing:

```
let first = "https://joytst.page.link/zMx3nAj9DxwcE1JC9?title=New+calendar+test"
let second = "https://joytst.page.link/zMx3nAj9DxwcE1JC9?title=New%20calendar%20test"

let firstOutput = first.removingPercentEncoding //https://joytst.page.link/zMx3nAj9DxwcE1JC9?title=New+calendar+test
let secondOutput = second.removingPercentEncoding //https://joytst.page.link/zMx3nAj9DxwcE1JC9?title=New calendar test
```

1. Why doesn't it remove encoding correctly, since + is a correct encoding for space?
2. How can I correctly decode both of them, no matter which one I receive?

Comment: What do you mean "+ is a correct encoding for space"?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6855723/2725435) it is correct.

Comment: It says "_Most_ server side scripts would decode..." so it isn't exactly a rule and I assume swift URL handling is more focused on creating and sending URL's rather than receiving and decoding them so this could also be a reason why you don't get the expected result..

Comment: Apparently percent encoding is not same thing as URL encoding where space can be encoded as `+` character.

Comment: Isn't percent encoding having "percent" in its name, so "+" having no "%" isn't "decoded"? Is should have been `%2B` to be `+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Why” is a difficult question to answer except for the people who had a hand in implementing [`CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapes`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/CoreFoundation/URL.subproj/CFURL.c#L1115). The fact is that it doesn't.

I can speculate that it doesn't because the `+` for space replacement is not part of [RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986). It should only be used in the query part of the URL, which is of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. But this is just my guess.

Anyway, if you want to convert `+` to space, you should do so before performing percent-decoding, lest you decode `%2b` into `+` and then further decode it into a space, leaving no way for your URL to contain a genuine `+` after decoding.

```
let firstOutput = first
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: " ")
    .removingPercentEncoding
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could decode a whitespace from two different patters, then when you wanted to do the opposite and encode it which one it should take?

That's the reason why `removingPercentEncoding` only supports one of them.