# Why do I have to remove percent encoding twice for an encoded string?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my simple extension:

```
extension String {
    var urlDecoded: String? {
        replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%20").removingPercentEncoding
    }
}
```

And here is my string:

```
let string = "https%253A%252F%252Fplz.pl"
```

After I call

```
let firstDecoded = string.urlDecoded

// "https%3A%2F%2Fplz.pl"

let secondDecoded = string.urlDecoded?.urlDecoded

// "https://plz.pl"
```

Why do I have to call it twice? How can I do it correctly and quickly?

Comment: Where does that string come from? Where and why has it been decoded twice?

Comment: Related question from the question author yesterday: [Why removingPercentEncoding does not replace + like it does with %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75473592/why-removingpercentencoding-does-not-replace-like-it-does-with-20)

Comment: The answer should be obvious by *looking at the data*. Did you expect, for example, that a single call would translate `%253A` to `:`? Why? (Hint: do you know what the encoding is for `:`? Or for `%`? If you have a question about what the code for an encoder or decoder is doing, the first thing should be to make sure you *understand the encoding*.)

Comment: A lead is that [ASCII "%"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) is 0x25.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have to decode it twice? Because it's been encoded twice.

The ASCII code point for the percent symbol is 0x25. So `%25` in an encoded URL encodes a percent symbol. Thus:

```
https%253A%252F%252Fplz.pl
     └┬┘  └┬┘  └┬┘
https % 3A % 2F % 2Fplz.pl
      └┬─┘ └┬─┘ └┬─┘
https  :    /    /  plz.pl
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the input is encoded twice.

`%253A`: `%25` is an encoded `%` meaning it results in `%3A` after the first decoding and `:` after the second decoding.